# How to pass a parameter using Ajax.request in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to pass a parameter when making an Ajax request and retrieve it in `.done` when the request is successful.
Any idea how to do it?

```
var requestFeed;
requestFeed = Ajax.request(url, {
                    method: 'GET',
                    type: 'json',
                    cache: true,
                    timeout: CONFIG.ajax.timeout
                });
requestFeed.done(function(resp, myParameter){ // NOTE HERE
// get myParameter and do smt with data
});
```

Comment: Well the response you expect is json as far as I understand, so what is the problem to return it in resp and access it like resp.myParameter?

Comment: My parameter is not related to the resp I get. I need to be able to pass it programmatically.

Comment: Well this is the callback of the request and it might be with certain signature. The option is to extend the `Ajax` and allow it to accept more parameters, not related to the request, but this however might get tricky as it is possible that the successful request may occur in before `myParameter` is set correctly.

Comment: You need to override **bind()** method to set your second parameter. [here](https://github.com/maximebf/php-debugbar/issues/156) is an example of overriding prototype method.

Comment: Well it looks like you just need access to something in the callback. looks like a scoping issue to me. Maybe this is an xy problem? can you elaborate what you're actually trying to do? Why do you need to get the value strictly as a parameter to `.done()`? isn't there any other way to access it in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to send your "myParameter" value to the server you could do something like that

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: url,
    data: { ParameterNameOnServer: myParameter }
}).done(function (returndata) {
    alert(returndata);
});
```